# Перенос ф-ла из *.bat в *.jar

Tags: java, bat, rxjava, рефлексия

Всем привет. Хочу написать код для запуска на Джаве (создать джарник). 
Есть батник run.bat он делает запуск вида

```
set SAMPLE_PROPERTIES= -Dsamples.trustAll=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties

"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java %SAMPLE_PROPERTIES% -cp "%LOCALCLASSPATH%" -Xmx1024M com.web.Main %ARG%
```

запуск батника из смд все классно работает

```
run.bat com.web.task.Start -url "http://..." -username "..." -password "..." -basic "true"
```

**начинаются проблемы:** 
1. если эту команду поместить в другой батник testRun.bat и запустить так:

```
call run.bat com.web.task.Start -url "http://..." -username "..." -password "..." -basic "true"
```

Вылетает екзепшн

```
    ERROR: Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user
 name or password.
```

1. Если создать класс и запустить так (тот же екзепшн что и в п.1):

   ```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c cd "test" & start .\run.bat com.web.task.Start -url "http://..." -username "..." -password "..." -basic "true"
   ```
2. Если создать класс вида:

   ```
   import com.web.Main;
   public class App {
       public static void main(String[]args1) throws Throwable {
           String[] args = {
                   "com.web.task.Start"
                   "-url", "http://...",
                   "-username", "...",
                   "-password", "...", 
                   "-basic", "true"
           };
           Main.main(args);
       }
   }
   ```

Получаем екзепшн вида:

```
ERROR: com.web.connect.Connection
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.web.connect.Connection
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at com.web.param.Param.inject(Param.java:231)
    at com.web.samples.SampleRef.run(SampleRef.java:87)
    at com.web.Main.run(Main.java:282)
    at com.web.Main.sampleSwitching(Main.java:24)
    at com.web.Main.registeredSample(Main.java:69)
    at com.web.Main.main(Main.java:332)
    at com.web.App.main(App.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.web.connect.Connection.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 12 more
```

Куда копать? - Помогите плиз ...
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, неправильно передает параметры. ВО втором батнике я бы первым делом заключил все параметры в кавычки: `call 'run.bat...'`? хотя я по батникам не эксперт. По поводу вашего java-кода я сейчас не могу ничего сказать, но вот кусок кода, который решает подобную задачу: устанавливает переменные среды и запускает на выполнение Jar-файл (второй экземпляр самого себя, строго говоря), после чего заканчивает работу.
Посмотрите, как я это делал, может поможет.

```
  **
  * Uner Linux, sets the required environment variables 
  * and runs another instance of the program in a child process
  * having these variables in effect.      
  * @param envVars the list of vars to set, each must have a form "name=value"
  */
  private static void setEnvVars(String... envVars) {
    boolean hasToSet = false;
    StringBuilder commandBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String envVar: envVars) {
      String name = envVar.split("=")[0];
      if (System.getenv(name) == null) {
        hasToSet = true;
        commandBuilder.append("export " + envVar + "; ");
      }
    }
    if (!hasToSet) return; // nothing to do

    String className = Controller.class.getName();
    URL classResource = Controller.class.getResource("Controller.class");
    boolean fromJar = classResource.getProtocol().equals("rsrc");
    String jarName = classResource.getFile();

    if (!jarName.startsWith("/")) {
      jarName =  ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(jarName)
                  .getFile().split("!")[0].replaceAll("file:", "");
    } // else it's not a jar and this var is ignored 

    commandBuilder.append(
        fromJar? 
            "java -jar " + jarName :      // if runs from jar
            "java -cp ./bin/:../ExtLibs/swt_linux64/swt_linux64.jar:"
            + "../_JavaHelp_SWT/bin:../ExtLibs/_MyWrenchedLibs/javahelp-2.0.05.jar " // if runs from under Eclipse or somewhat alike 
            + className );

    String[] script = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", commandBuilder.toString() };

    try {
      Process p = new ProcessBuilder(script).start();
      p.waitFor(30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    System.exit(0);
  }
```

Comment: Ок. Спасибо за решение, сейчас буду разбираться ... 
PS/ а с кавычками, чего я уже только не перепробовал, либо рагуется параметры, либо екепшн, что указал выше